How can I adress a specific device in my Android app via HTTP1 v1 API?
I am programming an Android app in java in Android Studio, where people log in with their gmail adress and their chosen user name, their email and the token (task.getResult()) is stored in a firebase databse and wanted to know  how I can send a notification to a specific device in my Android app via HTTP1 v1 API.

First review the API documentation and maybe the migration guide, then edit your question to show specifically what you tried that doesn't work the way you expect, along with you debugging details.
